# Sending MESSAGE to a person on facebook using python

Tags: python, api, facebook, scripting

I want to make a script that can be used to send messages to our friends on facebook.
How do I proceed? Which is the best module to use?

Comment: +1, why the downvote? Perfectly good programming related question.

Comment: My motive is that I want myself to be notified of some even occurred to my mobile through sms. And as in my country, FACEBOOK provides free sms updates, I can send a message to myself, so that I would get instant notification of some event..

Comment: I'm writing a script to assign secret Santas, so that no one knows who has who. I don't have some of my friends' email addresses, but I do have them on Facebook. I sure there are literally tens of other reasons to need to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may indeed want [pyfacebook](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) as another answer suggested, though the URL I'm giving (on github.com) is where the project (esp. its source;-) actually lives.

A simple survey of Python APIs for facebook is [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Python), and it also points to a possibly-simpler but less complete API, if you want to run in Google App Engine, i.e., [simplefacebook](https://bitbucket.org/srirangan/simplefacebook).  `pyfacebook` does not limit you to App Engine specifically, though it can support it of course.

A pyfacebook tutorial is [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:PyFacebook_Tutorial) -- it even briefly shows how to use it from an interactive interpreter (!), though the bulk of the tutorial is about doing web apps, of course.

Comment: I just wanna confirm that can i send Personal Messages using that?

Comment: @Shadyabhi, looks like you can, within all Facebook policy constraints of course, cfr e.g. http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notes.create (user must grant `create_note` extended permission).

Answer (score 0):

[PyFacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) is a Python client library for the Facebook API.